# Jenkins is not using given SCM credentials for shared library

Tags: jenkins, svn, shared-libraries, credentials

I have bin configuring a globally shared library correctly as it is shown to me in the global configuration of the Jenkins Server. In a Pipeline Job I try to use the specified library, but I get the error message, that no credentials were used to checkout the library from SCM.

**Library Configuration**

[image]

- Name: `LIBRARY`
- Default version: `trunk` -- *Currently maps to revision: 125*
- Load implicitly: `[ ]`
- Allow default version to be overridden: `[x]`
- Include @Library changes in job recent changes: `[x]`
- Modern SCM `(o)`
- Legacy SCM `( )`
- Git `( )`
- GitHub `( )`
- Mercurial `( )`
- Subversion `(o)`
- Project Repository Base: `http://scrambled/url/repo/LIBRARY`
- Credentials: `Scrambly/******`
- Include branches: `trunk, tags/*`

**Pipeline**

```
@Library('LIBRARY@trunk')

pipeline {
    // Imagine some content //
}
```

**Error Message**

```
Checking out http://scrambled/url/repo/LIBRARY at revision 123
Using sole credentials <none> in realm ‘<http://scrambled> Scrambler’
ERROR: Subversion checkout has been canceled
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: ISVNAuthentication provider did not provide credentials; HTTP authorization cancelled.
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:694)
Caused: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: E200015: ISVNAuthentication provider did not provide credentials; HTTP authorization cancelled.
svn: E200015: ISVNAuthentication provider did not provide credentials; HTTP authorization cancelled.
```

---

I do not understand it says there were `<none>` credentials in the error message, although I configured the shared library to use specific credentials.

Thank you all in advice.

Comment: Cloud you show your globally shared library configuration, you can screenshot it and put it in your question.

Comment: @yong Added as image and as text.

Answer (score 0):

i fix this problem by using https git url :

```sh
https://{username}:{passwd}@xxxxx.git
```